# How to run MySQLi query dynamically

Tags: php, mysqli, dynamic

Is there any way to run mysqli query dynamically ? I am working on a small project who has dynamic form generation option. And then they want to filer those forms. Obviously we dont know how much will be form fields and how many filters they want. So is there any such way through which I can perform this action? Suppose if i can do something

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE fld1 = 1 OR fld2 = 2 OR fld3 = 3....
```

Where those 1, 2, 3,... Can be something or maybe its empty depend on filters.

Comment: Everthing can be done `dynamically`! Tipp: Collect and join conditions like: `$coll[]= 'fld1 = 1'; $coll[]= 'fld2 = 2';  echo "SELECT * FROM table WHERE ".implode(' OR ',$coll);`

Answer (score 1):

You can dynamically build your query in php by examining your `$_POST` values and then building out your where statement. Here's some pseudo code

```
foreach($_POST as $name=>$value)
{
    $where[] = "`$key` = '$value'";
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE ".implode("OR", $where);
```

Of course you will need to either sanitize or use a prepared statement to make sure this is safe.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to run it dynamically is by using PDO and classes, if youre confused about any of those two things check out the PHPGuru Jeffery Way found here: https://laracasts.com/series/php-for-beginners and check out his PHP tutorials, youll quickly learn what you need to do to be able to make a class that allows you to dynamically connect to your database!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe do something like:

```
$Where = array();
foreach($_POST['form-field'] as $Field=>$Value){
 if($Value){
   $Where[] = $Field."=".$Value;
 }
}
$Query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE ".implode(" OR ",$Where);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **IN** clause of in MySQL query.

Similar like this.

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE fld1 IN (1, 2, 3);
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: This would only work if there is only one column to check. But he mention 3 and some "..." so this is not a good answer.

Answer (score -1):

```
$filter = '';
$filter .= 'fld1 = 1 OR ';
$filter .= 'fld2 = 2 OR ';
$filter .= 'fld3 = 3 OR ';
...
...
if(!empty($filter)) {
    $filter = substr($filter,0,-2); // delete last OR
}
$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE ".$filter."";
...
```

Something like this would work, you have to modify the way you populate `$filter`

Hope this'll help.